# PayPal SDK - AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, paypal

I am using the PayPal SDK with Django (Django REST Framework) to create and capture transactions. Following this [guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/capture-transaction/) I get the error in the title. It looks like `self.client.execute(request)` returns `paypalhttp.http_response.HttpResponse object` but Django won't let me return that from my view. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> returns paypalhttp.http_response.HttpResponse object

Pull the data out of that object, using whatever methods it has.  Typically you'll want to store the resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID).

Then [return a JSON response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) to the calling JS. Ever since django 1.7 you can just do something like:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse

    data = {
        'name': 'Vitor',
        'location': 'Finland',
        'is_active': True,
        'count': 28
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Obviously replace `data` with the actual response data you want to forward.

---

The client side JS should have proper error handling when it receives the response, see the demo pattern https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server